# Changing from layouts .xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a newbie in Android Studio so I created 3 `xml` layouts. But when I want to change from one layout to another using a button with `setContentView` twice, it crashes.

How can I change from one layout to another? I have heard about using something like `ViewFlipper` but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The easyest way of achieving this is to start a new activity on your button click, it will show your 2.xml (and another activity for your 3.xml). Another option would be the use of fragments, but more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Check this about ViewFlipper.
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/viewflipper.php

Comment: Link answers are not recommended; also. this should be better placed as a comment

Comment: Thanks you Syed, but i didn't understood .